# selenium-webdriver: Error: chrome.setDefaultService is not a function

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver v 4.3.1 which is the latest version atm. I have the code below:

```js
const chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");
const service = new chrome.ServiceBuilder(myChromePath).build();
chrome.setDefaultService(service);
```

Which gives the following error:

```
(node:111637) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: chrome.setDefaultService is not a function
```

Anybody knows how to resolve this error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation, I changed my code to something similar to this:

```js
 *     let chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
 *
 *     let service = new chrome.ServiceBuilder()
 *         .loggingTo('/my/log/file.txt')
 *         .enableVerboseLogging()
 *         .build();
 *
 *     let options = new chrome.Options();
 *     // configure browser options ...
 *
 *     let driver = chrome.Driver.createSession(options, service);
 *
```

You can see how you can pass the service object to `createSession` instead of setting the service object using `setDefaultService`.

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/6222bb2a1fc6d88ae5ff11c8ab7af06ef875d0b9/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js#L62

Answer (score 0):

```
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const service = new chrome.ServiceBuilder(path.join(__dirname, file_path));
try{
    driver = await new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser("chrome")
        .setChromeService(service)
        .withCapabilities(options)
        .build();
}catch(e){
    console.error('build fail');
    console.error(e);
    return;
}
```

If your chromedriver is in this directory, then filepath = './chromedriver.exe'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).